# DBT pass wrong value in cte models

Tags: jinja2, dbt

## **Problem**

I use a macros function to modify value in cte. How ever, it's always pass wrong value. The result from print always is:

*Running some_macro: 0, level

```
        final_table as (
        select
            toDate(`log_time`, 'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh') as `report_date`,
            `social_type`,
            `platform_id`,
            {{ map_level_to_level_range("level") }} as `segment_level`,
            `level`
        from last_user_action
```

my macros:

```
{% macro map_level_to_level_range(level) %}
{% set numeric_level = level|int %}
{{ print("Running some_macro: " ~ numeric_level ~ ", " ~ level) }}
{% if numeric_level in range(0, 5) %} '00 - 04'
{% elif numeric_level in range(5, 10) %} '05 - 09'
{% elif numeric_level in range(10, 15) %} '10 - 14'
{% elif numeric_level in range(15, 20) %} '15 - 19'
{% elif numeric_level in range(20, 25) %} '20 - 24'
{% elif numeric_level in range(25, 30) %} '25 - 29'
{% elif numeric_level in range(30, 35) %} '30 - 34'
{% elif numeric_level in range(35, 40) %} '35 - 39'
{% elif numeric_level in range(40, 45) %} '40 - 44'
{% elif numeric_level in range(45, 50) %} '45 - 49'
{% elif numeric_level in range(50, 55) %} '50 - 54'
{% elif numeric_level in range(55, 60) %} '55 - 59'
{% elif numeric_level in range(60, 65) %} '60 - 64'
{% elif numeric_level in range(65, 75) %} '65 - 74'
{% elif numeric_level in range(75, 85) %} '75 - 84'
{% elif numeric_level in range(85, 100) %} '85 - 99'
{% elif numeric_level in range(100, 115) %} '100 - 114'
{% elif numeric_level in range(115, 130) %} '115 - 129'
{% elif numeric_level in range(130, 150) %} '130 - 149'
{% elif numeric_level >= 150 %} '150+'
{% else %} '-1'
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

## **Wrong result**

You can compare it's with the result table follow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFFle.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you're passing a static string "level" to the macro, not the `level` value itself.

Since the `level` value is from table, you will need return a SQL statement from your macro to make the comparison occur in the database:

```sql
{% macro map_level_to_level_range(column_name) %}
CASE  
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN '00 - 04'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 5 AND 10 THEN '05 - 09'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 10 AND 15 THEN '10 - 14'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 15 AND 20 THEN '15 - 19'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 20 AND 25 THEN '20 - 24'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 25 AND 30 THEN '25 - 29'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 30 AND 35 THEN '30 - 34'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 35 AND 40 THEN '35 - 39'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 40 AND 45 THEN '40 - 44'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 45 AND 50 THEN '45 - 49'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 50 AND 55 THEN '50 - 54'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 55 AND 60 THEN '55 - 59'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 60 AND 65 THEN '60 - 64'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 65 AND 75 THEN '65 - 74'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 75 AND 85 THEN '75 - 84'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 85 AND 100 THEN '85 - 99'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 100 AND 115 THEN '100 - 114'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 115 AND 130 THEN '115 - 129'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} BETWEEN 130 AND 150 THEN '130 - 149'
  WHEN {{ column_name }} >= 150 THEN '150+'
  ELSE '-1'
END
{% endmacro %}
```